# Already tracked files merge automatically in a particular path without conflicting

Tags: git

I have say 3 branches for 3 different services. Lets call these branches `develop-service1`, `develop-service2`,`develop-service3`. And there is a master branch which has all the changes in these three branches.

The `develop-service1` branch modifies only files under `service1` folder and so does the other 2 branches.

Sometimes the most urgent bugfixes go to master. So there is a requirement that I might have to merge master to these three branches after the bug fix goes out for deployment.

My question is while being in say `develop-service1` I want the `service2` folders and `service3` folders to be in sync with whatever is in the master whenever I merge master, without any conflicts. (Ideally take whatever change is in master and ignore the one in `develop-service1`).

I do not know if there are other flavours of the very same question. I tried searching but somehow not convinced that that is the right question I was looking an answer for.

Comment: If the workflow you described is applied, what reason could there be for a file in `service2` folder to change on `develop-service1` branch? You should not expect conflicts here unless these branches modify the contents of the other folders.

Answer (score 0):

If each branch only deals with a specific directory/service, then merging any of them should not cause any conflicts.
If a bug fix has been committed directly to master, and you want that change reflected in each branch, it should be perfectly safe to merge master into each of those branches.

```
git checkout develop-service1
git merge master

git checkout develop-service2
git merge master
```

Etc.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is valid. Now let's imagine this situation (automatic merging). There's a new commit in `origin/master` and it automatically merges the changes to your `develop-service2` and `develop-service3` branches. Later on, you discover the local changes in these branches are lost and wander this should have been a manual process where you would selectively merge the latest changes from `origin/master` i.e. resolve conflicts. GIT gives you this provision exclusively to keep you out of this trouble situation in conflicting situations and since you know your code better (and not GIT; it's not so intelligent ;) you can resolve those conflicts better. To make this process smoother do frequent commits and merging so that you integrate the changes in small chunks and don't face bigger problems after merging. Let me know if you want to understand more in-depth.